# PyTorch: Dataloader creates a new dimension when creating batches

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, dataloader

I am seeing that when looping over the my `Dataloader()` obect using `enumerate()` I am getting a new dimension that is being coerced in order to create the batches of my data.

I have 4 Tensors that I am slicing at a macro level (I am panel data so I slice the data in blocks of individuals instead of rows (or observations)):

- `X` (3D)
- `Y` (2D)
- `Z` (2D)
- `id` (2D).

In the data I have 10 observations but only 5 individuals on the sample (hence, each individual has 2 observations) on my dataset. Thus, each batch on my data has a minimum of two observations.

Since I am setting the `batch_size = 2`, I am taking 4 observations for the first and second batch, and only 2 for the third.

This behavior is represented in the output below:

```
Selection of the data for by __getitem__ for individual 1
torch.Size([2, 3, 3]) X_batch when selecting for ind 1
torch.Size([2, 3]) Z_batch when selecting for ind 1
torch.Size([2, 1]) Y_batch when selecting for ind 1


Selection of the data for by __getitem__ for individual 2
torch.Size([2, 3, 3]) X_batch when selecting for ind 2
torch.Size([2, 3]) Z_batch when selecting for ind 2
torch.Size([2, 1]) Y_batch when selecting for ind 2


Data of the Batch #  1 inside the enumerate
shape X (outside foo) torch.Size([2, 2, 3, 3]) # <<-- here I have a new dimension
shape Z (outside foo) torch.Size([2, 2, 3])
shape Y (outside foo) torch.Size([2, 2, 1])


Selection of the data for by __getitem__ for individual 3
torch.Size([2, 3, 3]) X_batch when selecting for ind 3
torch.Size([2, 3]) Z_batch when selecting for ind 3
torch.Size([2, 1]) Y_batch when selecting for ind 3


Selection of the data for by __getitem__ for individual 4
torch.Size([2, 3, 3]) X_batch when selecting for ind 4
torch.Size([2, 3]) Z_batch when selecting for ind 4
torch.Size([2, 1]) Y_batch when selecting for ind 4


Data of the Batch #  2 inside the enumerate 
shape X (outside foo) torch.Size([2, 2, 3, 3])  # <<-- here I have a new dimension
shape Z (outside foo) torch.Size([2, 2, 3])
shape Y (outside foo) torch.Size([2, 2, 1])


Selection of the data for by __getitem__ for individual 5
torch.Size([2, 3, 3]) X_batch when selecting for ind 5
torch.Size([2, 3]) Z_batch when selecting for ind 5
torch.Size([2, 1]) Y_batch when selecting for ind 5


Data of the Batch #  3 inside the enumerate 
shape X (outside foo) torch.Size([1, 2, 3, 3]) # <<-- here I have a new dimension
shape Z (outside foo) torch.Size([1, 2, 3])
shape Y (outside foo) torch.Size([1, 2, 1])
```

First, I select the data that corresponds to the first and second individual but inside of the `enumerate()` loop I am getting a new dimension (`[0]`) which python is using to put the blocks if individuals.

---

So here is my question:

**Is there any way of concatening `torch.cat(, axis = 0)` the blocks of data instead of creating this new dimension in order to store the entire batch of data?**

So for instance for the first individual I want the following

```
Data of the Batch #  1 inside the enumerate
shape X (outside foo) torch.Size([4, 3, 3]) # <<-- here I torch.concat(,axis = 0)
shape Z (outside foo) torch.Size([4, 3])
shape Y (outside foo) torch.Size([4, 1])
```

The code that produces the output below is listed at the end. Thank you

---

#### Sample data

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import argparse

# args to be passed to the model
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Neural network for Flexible utility (VOT =f(z))')
args = parser.parse_args("") 
args.J = 3 # number of alternatives

# Sample data
X =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x1_1': {0: -0.1766214634108258, 1: 1.645852185286492, 2: -0.13348860101031038, 3: 1.9681043689968933, 4: -1.7004428240831382, 5: 1.4580091413853749, 6: 0.06504113741068565, 7: -1.2168493676768384, 8: -0.3071304478616376, 9: 0.07121332925591593}, 'x1_2': {0: -2.4207773498298844, 1: -1.0828751040719462, 2: 2.73533787008624, 3: 1.5979611987152071, 4: 0.08835542172064115, 5: 1.2209786277076156, 6: -0.44205979195950784, 7: -0.692872860268244, 8: 0.0375521181289943, 9: 0.4656030062266639}, 'x1_3': {0: -1.548320898226322, 1: 0.8457342014424675, 2: -0.21250514722879738, 3: 0.5292389938329516, 4: -2.593946520223666, 5: -0.6188958526077123, 6: 1.6949245117526974, 7: -1.0271341091035742, 8: 0.637561891142571, 9: -0.7717170035055559}, 'x2_1': {0: 0.3797245517345564, 1: -2.2364391598508835, 2: 0.6205947900678905, 3: 0.6623865847688559, 4: 1.562036259999875, 5: -0.13081282910947759, 6: 0.03914373833251773, 7: -0.995761652421108, 8: 1.0649494418154162, 9: 1.3744782478849122}, 'x2_2': {0: -0.5052556836786106, 1: 1.1464291788297152, 2: -0.5662380273138174, 3: 0.6875729143723538, 4: 0.04653136473130827, 5: -0.012885303852347407, 6: 1.5893672346098884, 7: 0.5464286050059511, 8: -0.10430829457707284, 9: -0.5441755265313813}, 'x2_3': {0: -0.9762973303149007, 1: -0.983731467806563, 2: 1.465827578266328, 3: 0.5325950414202745, 4: -1.4452121324204903, 5: 0.8148816373643869, 6: 0.470791989780882, 7: -0.17951636294180473, 8: 0.7351814781280054, 9: -0.28776723200679066}, 'x3_1': {0: 0.12751822396637064, 1: -0.21926633684030983, 2: 0.15758799357206943, 3: 0.5885412224632464, 4: 0.11916562911189271, 5: -1.6436210334529249, 6: -0.12444368631987467, 7: 1.4618564171802453, 8: 0.6847234328916137, 9: -0.23177118858569187}, 'x3_2': {0: -0.6452955690715819, 1: 1.052094761527654, 2: 0.20190339195326157, 3: 0.6839430295237913, 4: -0.2607691613858866, 5: 0.3315513026670213, 6: 0.015901139336566113, 7: 0.15243420084881903, 8: -0.7604225072161022, 9: -0.4387652927008854}, 'x3_3': {0: -1.067058994377549, 1: 0.8026914180717286, 2: -1.9868531745912268, 3: -0.5057770735303253, 4: -1.6589569342151713, 5: 0.358172252880764, 6: 1.9238983803281329, 7: 2.2518318810978246, 8: -1.2781475121874357, 9: -0.7103081175166167}})
Y = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'CHOICE': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 2.0, 9: 2.0}})
Z = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'z1': {0: 2.4196730570917233, 1: 2.4196730570917233, 2: 2.822802255159467, 3: 2.822802255159467, 4: 2.073171091633643, 5: 2.073171091633643, 6: 2.044165101485163, 7: 2.044165101485163, 8: 2.4001241292606275, 9: 2.4001241292606275}, 'z2': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}, 'z3': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 3.0, 9: 3.0}})
id = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id_choice': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0, 6: 7.0, 7: 8.0, 8: 9.0, 9: 10.0}, 'id_ind': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 3.0, 6: 4.0, 7: 4.0, 8: 5.0, 9: 5.0}} )
# Create a dataframe with all the data 
data = pd.concat([id,X, Z, Y], axis=1)
```

#### Defining the `torch.utils.data.Dataset()`

```
# class to create a dataset for choice data
class ChoiceDataset_all(Dataset):
    '''
    Dataset for choice data

    Args:
        data (pandas dataframe): dataframe with all the data

    Returns:
        dictionary with the data for each individual

    '''
    def __init__(self, data,  args , id_variable:str = "id_ind" ):

        if id_variable not in data.columns:
            raise ValueError(f"Variable {id_variable} not in dataframe")
        
        self.data = data
        # select cluster variable
        self.cluster_ids = self.data[id_variable].unique()
        self.Y = torch.LongTensor(self.data['CHOICE'].values -1).reshape(len(self.data['CHOICE'].index),1)
        self.id = torch.LongTensor(self.data[id_variable].values).reshape(len(self.data[id_variable].index),1)
        # number of individuals (N_n)
        self.N_n = torch.unique(self.id).shape[0]
        # number of choices made per individual (t_n)
        _ , self.t_n = self.id.unique(return_counts=True)
        #total number of observations (N_t = total number of choices)
        self.N_t = self.t_n.sum(axis=0).item() 
        # Select regressors: variables that start with "x"
        self.X_wide = data.filter(regex='^x') 
        # turn X_wide into a tensor
        self.X = torch.DoubleTensor(self.X_wide.values)
        # number of regressors (K)
        self.K = int(self.X_wide.shape[1] / args.J)
        # reshape X to have the right dimensions
        # Select variables that start with "z"
        self.Z = torch.DoubleTensor(self.data.filter(regex='^z').values)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.N_n # number of individuals

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # select the index of the individual
        self.index = torch.where(self.id == idx+1)[0]
        self.len_batch =  self.index.shape[0] 
        # Select observations for the individual
        Y_batch = self.Y[self.index]
        Z_batch = self.Z[self.index]
        id_batch = self.id[self.index]
        X_batch = self.X[self.index]
        # reshape X_batch to have the right dimensions
        X_batch = X_batch.reshape(self.len_batch,self.K,args.J)
        print("\n")
        print("Selection of the data for by __getitem__ for individual", idx+1)
        print(X_batch.shape, "X_batch when selecting for ind", idx+1)
        print(Z_batch.shape, "Z_batch when selecting for ind", idx+1)
        print(Y_batch.shape, "Y_batch when selecting for ind", idx+1)
        #print(id_batch.shape, "id_batch when selecting for ind", idx+1)
        return {'X': X_batch, 'Z': Z_batch, 'Y': Y_batch, 'id': id_batch}
```

#### Looping over `torch.utils.data.DataLoader()`

```
choice_data = ChoiceDataset_all(data, args, id_variable="id_ind")
data_loader = DataLoader(choice_data, batch_size=2, shuffle=False, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)

for idx, data_dict in enumerate(data_loader):
    print("\n")
    print("Data of the Batch # ", idx+1, "inside the enumerate")
    print("shape X (outside foo)", data_dict['X'].shape)
    print("shape Z (outside foo)", data_dict['Z'].shape)
    print("shape Y (outside foo)", data_dict['Y'].shape)
#    print("shape id (outside foo)", data_dict['id'])
```

Comment: The collation of samples into batches is handled by the `collate_fn` function provided to `DataLoader`. The default collate function introduces a batch dimension but you could provide your own to do whatever you wanted, including concatenation.

Comment: Thank you so much @jodag, I wasn't aware of the `collate_fn`. I just posted a solution to the problem. Could you tell me if you would have done it differently? Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @jodag I extended my answer profiling my custom `collate_fn` and a different approach proposed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-dataloader-creates-a-new-dimension-when-creating-batches/173719/2?u=alvarogutyerrez) which consisted on a simple `view` while looping. Do you have another in mind another (probably more efficient) customed `collate_fn` in mind that could outperform the other approach? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jorad I discovered the beauty of the `collate_fn`. Here is one solution to the problem.

```
def cust_collate(batch_dict):
    '''
    Collate function that concatenates the data for each individual using axis 0
    Args:
        batch_dict (dict): dictionary with the data for each individual
    Returns:
        batch_dict (dict): dictionary with the concatenated (axis = 0 ) data for each individual
    '''
    # concatenate the data for each individual using axis 0
    for i in range(len(batch_dict)):
        if i == 0:
            X = batch_dict[i]['X']
            Y = batch_dict[i]['Y']
            Z = batch_dict[i]['Z']
            id = batch_dict[i]['id']
        else:
            X = torch.cat((X, batch_dict[i]['X']), axis=0)
            Y = torch.cat((Y, batch_dict[i]['Y']), axis=0)
            Z = torch.cat((Z, batch_dict[i]['Z']), axis=0)
            id = torch.cat((id, batch_dict[i]['id']), axis=0)
    return {'X': X, 'Z': Z, 'Y': Y, 'id': id}

choice_data = ChoiceDataset_all(data, args, id_variable="id_ind")
data_loader = DataLoader(choice_data, batch_size=2, 
                         shuffle=False, num_workers=0, 
                         drop_last=False, 
                         collate_fn=cust_collate)

for idx, data_dict in enumerate(data_loader):
    print("\n")
    print("Data of the Batch # ", idx+1, "inside the enumerate")
    print("shape X (outside foo)", data_dict['X'].shape)
    print("shape Z (outside foo)", data_dict['Z'].shape)
    print("shape Y (outside foo)", data_dict['Y'].shape)
```

---

EDIT: Another suggestion was made at the [Official PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-dataloader-creates-a-new-dimension-when-creating-batches/173719/2?u=alvarogutyerrez), and I profileD both below. TLDR; a simple `view` while looping was faster than implementing my custom `collate_fn`.

Long answer below:

```
#%%
import torch
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import argparse
import cProfile
import pandas as pd
import torch


# class to create a dataset for choice data
class ChoiceDataset_all(Dataset):
    '''
    Dataset for choice data

    Args:
        data (pandas dataframe): dataframe with all the data

    Returns:
        dictionary with the data for each individual

    '''
    def __init__(self, data,  args , id_variable:str = "id_ind" ):

        if id_variable not in data.columns:
            raise ValueError(f"Variable {id_variable} not in dataframe")
        
        self.data = data
        self.args = args
        # select cluster variable
        self.cluster_ids = self.data[id_variable].unique()
        self.Y = torch.LongTensor(self.data['CHOICE'].values -1).reshape(len(self.data['CHOICE'].index),1)
        self.id = torch.LongTensor(self.data[id_variable].values).reshape(len(self.data[id_variable].index),1)
        # number of individuals (N_n)
        self.N_n = torch.unique(self.id).shape[0]
        # number of choices made per individual (t_n)
        _ , self.t_n = self.id.unique(return_counts=True)
        #total number of observations (N_t = total number of choices)
        self.N_t = self.t_n.sum(axis=0).item() 
        # Select regressors: variables that start with "x"
        self.X_wide = data.filter(regex='^x') 
        # turn X_wide into a tensor
        self.X = torch.DoubleTensor(self.X_wide.values)
        # number of regressors (K)
        self.K = int(self.X_wide.shape[1] / self.args.J)
        # reshape X to have the right dimensions
        # Select variables that start with "z"
        self.Z = torch.DoubleTensor(self.data.filter(regex='^z').values)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.N_n # number of individuals

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # select the index of the individual
        self.index = torch.where(self.id == idx+1)[0]
        self.len_batch =  self.index.shape[0] 
        #print("len_batch", self.len_batch)
        # Select observations for the individual
        Y_batch = self.Y[self.index]
        Z_batch = self.Z[self.index]
        id_batch = self.id[self.index]
        X_batch = self.X[self.index]
        # reshape X_batch to have the right dimensions
        X_batch = X_batch.reshape(self.len_batch,self.K,self.args.J)
        return {'X': X_batch, 'Z': Z_batch, 'Y': Y_batch, 'id': id_batch}        


# Extend this function to handle batch of tensors
def cust_collate(batch_dict):
    '''
    Collate function that concatenates the data for each individual using axis 0
    Args:
        batch_dict (dict): dictionary with the data for each individual
    Returns:
        batch_dict (dict): dictionary with the concatenated (axis = 0 ) data for each individual
    '''
    # concatenate the data for each individual using axis 0
    for i in range(len(batch_dict)):
        if i == 0:
            X = batch_dict[i]['X']
            Y = batch_dict[i]['Y']
            Z = batch_dict[i]['Z']
            id = batch_dict[i]['id']
        else:
            X = torch.cat((X, batch_dict[i]['X']), axis=0)
            Y = torch.cat((Y, batch_dict[i]['Y']), axis=0)
            Z = torch.cat((Z, batch_dict[i]['Z']), axis=0)
            id = torch.cat((id, batch_dict[i]['id']), axis=0)
    return {'X': X, 'Z': Z, 'Y': Y, 'id': id}


def resize_batch_3D_tensor(x:torch.Tensor):
    return  x.view(-1, x.size(2), x.size(3))

def resize_batch_2D_tensor(y:torch.Tensor):
    return  y.view(-1,  y.size(2))

#%% profiling the code



# Create a clustered dataset 

# args to be passed to the model
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Neural network for Flexible utility (VOT =f(z))')
args = parser.parse_args("") 
args.J = 3 # number of alternatives

# Data parameters
N = 10000
T = 500
N_t = N * T
K = 50
J = 3
# Create data
x = torch.randn((N_t, K * J ))
y = torch.randn((N_t,)).reshape(N_t,1)
# create correlative sequence of numbers using torch.arange with T observations per individual N
id_ind = torch.arange(1, N+1, 1).repeat(T).sort()[0].reshape(N_t,1)
data_sim = pd.DataFrame(torch.cat((x, y, id_ind), axis=1).numpy())
data_sim.columns = [f'x{i}' for i in range(K *J)] + ['CHOICE', 'id_ind']

# Defining the dataset
choice_data = ChoiceDataset_all(data_sim, args, id_variable="id_ind")
batch_size = 100
# Defining the dataloaders
DL_default_collate = DataLoader(choice_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)
DL_custom_collate = DataLoader(choice_data, batch_size=batch_size, collate_fn=cust_collate, shuffle=False, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)

# Functions to profile
def foo_custom(DL):
    for idx, data_dict in enumerate(DL):
        X = data_dict['X']
        Y = data_dict['Y']
    return True


def foo_default(DL):
    for idx, data_dict in enumerate(DL):
        X = resize_batch_3D_tensor(data_dict['X'])
        Y = resize_batch_2D_tensor(data_dict['Y'])

    return True
```

Profiling

```
# Profiling
custom_prof  = cProfile.run('foo_custom(DL_custom_collate)', sort='cumtime') 
# >> 71344 function calls in 151.814 seconds
default_prof = cProfile.run('foo_default(DL_default_collate)', sort='cumtime') 
# >> 35144 function calls (34744 primitive calls) in 67.471 seconds
```